# Why isn't Ruby on Rails correctly generating the 'notice' HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, query-string

The embedded ruby code in my view is...

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

but when the URL reads...

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects/3?notice=Project+was+successfully+created
```

the generated HTML is...

```
<p id="notice"></p>
```

I'm expecting it to read...

```
<p id="notice">Project was successfully created</p>
```

What gives?

**EDIT:**  Here's my controller code just to ease any curiosity..

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to(:action => "show", :id => @project, :notice => 'Project was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @project, :status => :created, :location => @project }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try assigning the value in the controller with something like

```
@notice_text = params[:notice]
```

and then you can use something like

```
<p id="notice><%= @notice_text %></p>
```

in your view.

[You may wish to read the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257839/rails-routing-with-query-string) which deals more explicitly with passing variables through URL query strings.

Comment: I don't understand, what's the point of the 'notice' convenience method then?  If I set the notice using :notice => 'Article was successfully created.' in my controller, shouldn't the '<%= notice %>' display it?

Comment: The flash[] hash is actually something different. You can assign to it from the controller as well. You may want to take a look at this post on "Useful flash messages in Rails" -- http://rubypond.com/blog/useful-flash-messages-in-rails

Comment: Thanks, Joe, I appreciate your help.  I guess what I'm asking is, shouldn't my code work for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Well -- it depends. In the view, 'notice' doesn't have any meaning, even if you try to assign something to it from the controller. The flash hash provided to the view is special in this sense. Other things you pass into the view need to use the '@' prefix; hence the '@notice_text'. So, as long as you assign the URL querystring value from the params[] hash to something in your controller (whether it's the flash[] hash or a variable like '@notice_text' in the example), you can grab it in the view. We didn't see your controller code, so I couldn't say whether it's exactly right or not...

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing exactly the same as BeachRunnerJoe and came across the answers here.  As I didn't like any, I did a bit of my own research.  I know this question/answer is over a year old.  Nonetheless, I thought I would post a belated answer anyway.

The following worked for me:

```
redirect_to( { :action => "show", :id => @project }, { :notice => 'Project was successfully created.' } )
```

The redirect_to method takes two parameters: *options* and *response_status*.  Without the extra { }s, Ruby interprets all parameters as belonging to *options* and therefore includes the :notice hash in the *options* for the URL.

Hope this helps.

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because the "notice" convenience method uses the flash, whereas you want to display the params, not the flash. Try instead of doing a redirect and assigning the notice in the params, to first assign the notice to a flash variable then redirect.

```
if @project.save
  flash[:notice] = 'Project was successfully created'
  redirect_to project_path(@project)
end
```

Comment: I just updated my question with my controller code, shouldn't that work?  thanks again!

Comment: No, that won't work, because you are passing the `:notice => 'Project ...'` in the redirect call, which passes the notice variable in the params hash (as a get variable in the url). You need to specify the notice variable in the flash instead. try this: `format.html { flash[:notice] = 'project success' and redirect_to(:action => :show, :id => @project.id) }`