# Validate paramaters in Restful endpoints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I am rookie in rails restful web service and i am trying build service that returns a json dump of deals.So far my app returns these deals in json format when you hit http://localhost:3000/api/deals. Now i want to add two mandatory parameters(deal_id and title) and two optional parameters in the uri `http://localhost:3000/api/deals?deal_id=2&title=book`. What is the best way to validate these two mandatory parameters?In other words I just want to do the query only if deal_id and title parameters are present. Assuming Deal model has fields deal_id, title, description and vendor.
Here is my code

Controller

```
  module Api
  class DealsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
   @deals = Deal.all
   respond_with (@deals)
  end
 end
end
```

routes

```
 namespace :api,:defaults => {format:'json'} do
 resources :deals
end
```

Comment: Accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257839/rails-routing-with-query-string) is nice with some options.  You can also use `contraints` in your route definitions to validate before the controller.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @steve klein Thank you But in my case i need help validating those two manadatory parameters  from what i have so far.

Comment: If your main question is about how to validate, perhaps you could update your post with your validation requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate presence of query parameters in a Rails route, you can use the `:constraints` option.  So, in your case, if you want to require the presence of parameters `deal_id` and `title`, you can do so by changing:

```
resources :deals
```

To:

```
resources :deals, :constraints => lambda{ |req| !req.params[:deal_id].blank? && !req.params[:title].blank? }
```

Then, in your controller, you can access all four parameters in the `params` hash.

Alternatively, if you want to provide more user friendly error messages, you can do validation in the controller.  There are a number of approaches.  I would probably do something like this:

```
def action
  if params[:deal_id].blank? || params[:title].blank?
    flash[:warning] = 'Deal ID and title must be present'
    redirect_to root_path and return
  end

  #rest of your code goes here
end
```

Comment: Thank you. How do you notify the client though? Can you do @deal.errors in the controller?

Comment: @Katie - I just updated my answer with an alternate solution.

Comment: Thank you .But just to keep in mind the errors are returned in json format as this is a web service.

Comment: Oops good point @Katie.  I'm assuming my answer will get you on the right track but let me know if you need assistance with formatting the error in json.